# Kali won't boot in GUI

Tags: software-installation, gnome, kali-linux, gui, startx

After installation of kali on 32 bit a terminal opened.
Entered command

```
startx
```

It says `command not found`

So I thought of installing gnome for the same purpose

```
Sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Sudo apt-get install -f gnome
```

It says `package gnome has no installation candidate`

Then I tried

```
Sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Apt-get install gdm3
```

It says `package gdm3 has no installation candidate`

What should I do?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/kali-linux/info

Comment: you should try a user friendly linux distribution, such as Mint or Ubuntu or Debian etc etc .... basically anything that is not Kali

Answer (score 0):

Kali 2020.1a had error in its image so it was not booting in GUI.
Kali just fixed this issue in 2020.1b version.